# iwidgets not found in tclsh, but are installed: Why?

Tags: tcl, yum

I find that both the itk and iwidgets packages cannot be found using tclsh using a "package require" statement. This is on Centos 7.9. Both of the packages are, however, installed as you can see from the yum/dnf output below. What could be the cause of this and ever more important what is a solution.

```
% tclsh
% package require Tk
 8.6.12
% package require Itcl
 4.2.2
% package require Itk
 can't find package Itk
% package require Iwidgets
 can't find package Iwidgets
% exit


(pymatgen) :/data>dnf list installed "itk-devel*"
Installed Packages
 itk-devel.x86_64  3.4- 9.el7         @System


(pymatgen) :/data>dnf list installed "iwidgets*"
Installed Packages
 iwidgets.noarch 4.0.2-9.el7          @System
```

EDIT
The result of "rpm -ql iwidgets | grep pkgIndex" is:
/usr/share/tcl8.5/iwidgets4.0.2/pkgIndex.tcl

while
:~>tclsh
% package require Iwidgets
join [lsort -dictionary [package names]] \ncan't find package Iwidgets
% exit

Here is the $auto_path result as well as the package list.

```
(base) :~>rpm -ql iwidgets | grep pkgIndex
/usr/share/tcl8.5/iwidgets4.0.2/pkgIndex.tcl
(base) :~>tclsh
% puts $auto_path
/data/miniconda/lib/tcl8.6 /data/miniconda/lib
% exit

% package require Iwidgets
join [lsort -dictionary [package names]] \ncan't find package Iwidgets
% 
http
Itcl
itcl
msgcat
opt
platform
sqlite3
Tcl
tcl::tommath
TclOO
tclreadline
tcltest
tdbc
tdbc::mysql
tdbc::odbc
tdbc::postgres
Thread
Tk
Ttrace
zlib
%
```

Comment: And does $auto_path contain /usr/share or /usr/share/tcl8.5? The `package require Iwidgets` was expected to throw an error, because nothing has changed. But I expected some output from a subsequent `join [lsort -dictionary [package names]] \n`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have easy access to a CentOS system, but you can use the following commands to investigate:

Find the pkgIndex.tcl file of the iwidgets package:
`rpm -ql iwidgets | grep pkgIndex`

Then in your tclsh, check that a parent directory is listed in the auto_path variable: `puts $auto_path`

You can also check the available packages. Maybe Iwidgets is only available as "iwidgets". Again inside a tclsh run:

```
package require Iwidgets
join [lsort -dictionary [package names]] \n
```

Note: You have to do a `package require` first so Tcl will scan the disk for available packages.

UPDATE: After you provided the value of your $auto_path, it seems that you are not using the standard CentOS tclsh, but probably a tclsh that came with miniconda. You can check with `which tclsh`.

I suspect that if you run /usr/bin/tclsh, the packages can be found. Unless the miniconda package replaced /usr/bin/tclsh, which would be bad.